# Installing a downloaded program (cruft)

Tags: software-installation

I downloaded cruft-0.2.tar.gz and extracted the files into a directory. Here is the list of files:

```
COPYING        cruft.1  cruft.doc  INSTALL   keygen.c  packing.list
cruft-0.2.lsm  cruft.c  cruft.h    keygen.1  Makefile
```

How do I install this program?
I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a configure file in the folder you extracted "cruft-0.2.tar.gz" to, open a terminal to that directory (to that path) and run

```
 ./configure
 make
 sudo make install
```

Comment: Since it doesn't look like there's a configure file included, you should just have to run

`make
sudo make install`

Comment: ./configure is supposed to create makefile..but as op says..its already there..so running make will do i guess